# OpenSSL perl configuration script fails with Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl, makefile

I'm trying to build OpenSSL but i have one big problem which i couldn't figure it out.

I reinstalled VS 2017, perl, strawberry, nasm but nothing worked.

`%PATH%` contains perl path, nasm path etc.

I found the same issue on github but still can't fix it. (My setup is x64)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If Perl says that `NASM` is not found, it is likely correct. Have you checked that `nasm.exe` is on the path? Type `nasm` to verify. Also, please [edit] your post and replace the screenshot image by text. This makes the post more readable and searchable.

Comment: %PATH% contains NASM correct path, that's weird..

Comment: Why do you say "nothing worked"? The first configuration `perl Configure VC-WIN64A no-asm` (i.e. C instead of assembler routines) obviously ran without error.

Comment: Are you sure that `nasm.exe` is in `%PATH%` in the command window you excuted the `perl Configure ...` in? F.ex. in *that command window* what does `nasm -v` print out?

Comment: It looks like it works but makefile isn't created. `nasm -v` show `NASM version 2.14.02 compiled on Dec 26 2018`

Comment: Your picture (PLEASE *do not* remove the `!` in your edits) shows two configuration runs, but no `make` invocation after the first, error-free, configuration. So: have you tried to run `make` after the first configuration run to make sure that C-only build works or not?

Comment: [Looking at](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/e766f4a0531bffdab8ad2038279b755928d7a40a/Configurations/10-main.conf#L8) you could try to write a test perl script with the line `print qx(nasm -v), "\n";` and run it in that command window to see what the problem might be in your environment.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that [this line](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/e766f4a0531bffdab8ad2038279b755928d7a40a/Configurations/10-main.conf#L8) in the OpenSSL code is causing your problem, because if it fails it triggers the error message described in your question:

```perl
if (`nasm -v 2>NUL` =~ /NASM version ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/ && $1 >= 2.0) {
```

You could try to debug this issue in your environment with the following stripped down test script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $output = <<END_OF_STRING;
NASM version 2.14.02 compiled on Dec 26 2018
test
some other junk
END_OF_STRING

if ($output =~ /NASM version ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/ && $1 >= 2.0) {
    print "TEST: NASM $1 found\n";
} else {
    die "TEST: NASM not found\n";
}

print "TEST with redirection to NUL: ", `nasm -v 2>NUL`;
print "TEST without redirection to NUL: ", `nasm -v`;

if (`nasm -v 2>NUL` =~ /NASM version ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/ && $1 >= 2.0) {
    print "REAL: NASM $1 found\n";
} else {
    die "REAL: NASM not found\n";
}

exit 0;
```

When I run it on my Linux machine I get:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
TEST: NASM 2.14 found
TEST with redirection to NUL: NASM version 2.13.03 compiled on Jul 14 2018
TEST without redirection to NUL: NASM version 2.13.03 compiled on Jul 14 2018
REAL: NASM 2.13 found
```

... and then I realized that I have `nasm` installed on that machine :-)

---

**Update 1:** based on your first run of the test script I would suggest to remove the `2>NUL` from the OpenSSL source line, i.e.:

```perl
if (`nasm -v` =~ /NASM version ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/ && $1 >= 2.0) {
```

This doesn't modify OpenSSL functionality, but probably helps you over the installation bump...

---

**Update 2:** digging a bit further I'm almost certain that the issue here is Strawberry Perl. To quote from the [home page](http://strawberryperl.com/):

> **Straberry Perl** is a perl environment for MS Windows containing all you need to run and develop perl applications. It is designed to be as close as possible to perl environment on UNIX systems.

That translates to `system(STRING)`, `qx{}` or backtick operators calling a UNIX shell, e.g. bash, and **not** `cmd.exe`. But

- the OpenSSL `VC-WIN64A` configuration hard-codes the `cmd.exe` command line `nasm -v 2>NUL`,
- that command line fails in Strawberry Perl shell,
- therefore `qx{nasm -v 2>NUL}` returns an empty string,
- resulting in the `m//` regex to fail,
- leading the configure script to a false negative.

In conclusion: either use the workaround I suggested or dig into the OpenSSL documentation if there is an alternative configuration option for Windows with Strawberry Perl.

Comment: Firstly, i'm running on Windows. Secondly, after running your script i get: `TEST: NASM 2.14 found
NASM version 2.14.02 compiled on Dec 26 2018
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at dummy.pl line 20.
REAL: NASM not found`

Comment: I know you are running on Windows, but that's beside the point. The test script has already narrowed down the issue, but the details got lost in comments. I updated the test script to print a bit more exact information. The error message indicates that the redirection `2>NUL` is not working in your environment. Have you tried `nasm -v 2>NUL` in your `CMD` window?

Comment: I think the issue here is Strawberry Perl. Updated my answer and question title accordingly.